# How to Edit .csproj files with PowerShell - Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, powershell

I need some help editing a csproj file using PowerShell. I basically need to select a node and alter it.

Example:

```
<None Include="T4\WebConfigSettingGeneratorScript.tt">
  <Generator>TextTemplatingFileGenerator</Generator>
  <LastGenOutput>WebConfigSettingGeneratorScript1.txt</LastGenOutput>
</None>
```

I need to remove the  TextTemplatingFileGenerator attribute from this tag.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I do this kind of thing a lot. I keep around a set of helper functions for manipulating XML files - particular C# project files. Try this out:

```
param($path)
$MsbNS = @{msb = 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003'}

function RemoveElement([xml]$Project, [string]$XPath, [switch]$SingleNode)
{
    $nodes = @(Select-Xml $XPath $Project -Namespace $MsbNS | Foreach {$_.Node})
    if (!$nodes) { Write-Verbose "RemoveElement: XPath $XPath not found" }
    if ($singleNode -and ($nodes.Count -gt 1)) { 
        throw "XPath $XPath found multiple nodes" 
    }
    foreach ($node in $nodes)

        $parentNode = $node.ParentNode
        [void]$parentNode.RemoveChild($node)
    }
}

$proj = [xml](Get-Content $path)
RemoveElement $proj '//msb:None/msb:Generator' -SingleNode
$proj.Save($path)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Where do I run this from? 

Do you know any way of selecting the current project or the startup project?

Comment: I would put this in a RemoveTTFileGeneratorNode.ps1 file (PowerShell script file) and then run it from the powershell prompt passing it the path to the C# project file.

Comment: Sorry to have to ask, but what's the syntax for running it from the ps prompt? - Sincerely powershell n00b

Comment: No problem.  The syntax would be: `C:\PS> c:\some_path\RemoveTTFileGeneratorNode.ps1 c:\some_path\foo.csproj`

Comment: @KeithHill just tried to run this script and got "Data at the root level is invalid". Did you mean to call RemoveElement $proj instead? (also $proj = [xml](Get-Content $path)). Regards,

Comment: @KeithHill sorry to bother you again. Also if I remove Write-Verbose and replace with a Console.WriteLine I'm getting "XPath not found" even if I put in "/Project". Any ideas? Im also a powershell noob trying to manipulate csproj files! Thanks!

Comment: @DrAndrew, yes it should be `RemoveElement $proj ...`.  Don't forget that any XML element name must be prefixed with `msb:` as in  `/msb:Project` because the element names in MSBuild files are in the `http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003' namespace.  Also, rather than user Console.WriteLine, use Write-Warning instead.